# How can i calculate the response time in the below code and print it on the console

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mocha.js

```
describe("Prefabs basic", function() {
    it("It should create simple plrefab", function(done) {
        var data = {
            name: "Pre",
            project: {
                _id: settings.projectId,
                name: "PM_40"
            },
            __t: "Prefabs",
            stage: "planning",
            multiTrade: {
                value: false,
                companies: []
            },
            owner: {
                user: {
                    _id: ""
                },
                company: {
                    _id: ""
                }
            },
            _customStage: "planning",
            dates: [],
            dateIndices: {
                additional: {},
                coord: 0,
                deliver: 1
            },
            fileIndices: [],
            todoIndices: [0],
            new_prefab: true,
            todos: [],
            items: {
                fileIndices: [],
                todoIndices: [],
                customId: "1",
                name: "Item0",
                level: "1",
                zone: "west"
            },
            keywords: ["This is Prefab"]
        };

        chai
            .request(server)
            .post("/v3/prefabs/create")
            .set("Authorization", settings.authKey)
            .send(data)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                prefab = res.body;
                prefabId = res.body._id;
                console.log(prefab);
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Going to have to make it readable if you want people to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of formatting your code so it is slightly more readable - in general you will get a better response to your questions if you present a question that is easy to understand.  With that said, you can use [`process.hrtime()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time) to time things in Node.  For example,

```
it('does something', function() {
    const startTime = process.hrtime();
    chai
        .request(server)
        .post("/v3/prefabs/create")
        .set("Authorization", settings.authKey)
        .send(data)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            res.should.have.status(200);

            const timeDifference = process.hrtime(startTime);

            console.log(`Request took ${timeDifference[0] * 1e9 + timeDifference[1]} nanoseconds`);
        });
});
```

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for your reply. I really appreciate. I have one question: If I want to print the time diff interms of Mili second, how would I do that?